# Inject custom block in custom position into checkout page

Tags: layout, configuration, static-block, custom-block

I'm stuck with injecting a block from my module into checkout page. The problem is that I need my block be inserted right before closing `<body>` tag, this is "before_body_end" position, as I know.

As I understand, I must put name of some `checkout` block into `<reference name="">` of my block. But I also need to put `<reference name="before_body_end">` there at the same time.

How can I achieve that? Or I'm completely wrong in my thoughts? My changes must be completely independent from system and thirdparty files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately or likely I had to figure out everything by myself. So the solution is:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block <your_block_specific_attributes_go_here> />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```